# How not to show form error messages using the autofocus directive when routing to a different component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular16

I'm building an authentication app using the PEAN stack (i.e., PostgreSQL - ExpressJS - Angular - NodeJS).

I have a directive for autofocus as follows:

**autofocus.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[autofocusDirective]',
})
export class AutofocusDirective {
  constructor(private host: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.host.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

It does the job perfectly in general.

#### Problem

However, if I click a button that navigates to another route, then I get an annoying glitch. In the example below, I clicked on the *Sign up* button, which takes the user to the Sign up component. In the exact moment I clicked on the button, the error message appeared for a split second on the Sign in component. I understand that the behavior described is expected. See the GIF below.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Question

**How not to show form error messages using the autofocus directive when routing to a different component?**

I handle form error messages as follows:

**sign-in.component.ts**

```
/* ... */

// Create a form group for sign in
formSignIn = new FormGroup({
  signInEmail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), // Email is a required field
  signInPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), // Password is a required field
});

// Get error message for email field
getErrorMessageEmail() {
  // If the email is not entered
  return this.formSignIn.controls['signInEmail'].hasError('required') ? 'Email is required' : '';
}

// Get error message for password field
getErrorMessagePassword() {
  // If the password is not entered
  return this.formSignIn.controls['signInPassword'].hasError('required') ? 'Password is required' : '';
}

/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks mostly like you are in a catch-22. If you focus on the input, it is no longer considered pristine and when you click something else, removing the focus, you are triggering the error for `Validators.required`.

Maybe instead change the validator to `Validators.email` (so that you are still validating the input) and in the login method called, if an email is not provided then manually assign the error `formSignIn.controls['signInEmail'].setErrors({'required': true})`. On successful login, you can remove the error or just ignore it since the component should be destroyed anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hm, this is not an option because the sign-in method is called on the *Sign in* button click, which is disabled until the whole form is valid. I need to display an error saying that the email is required before the user is able to click the button. Any other ideas?

Comment: If possible, could you throw your code on a stackblitz and post the link in your question? Then I could directly poke around the code and figure out a solution.